# How do I access a local network share in dolphin?

Tags: kubuntu, filemanager, dolphin, nas

I decided to switch over to Kubuntu for a while, and I backed up my documents on a NAS connected to my local network.  I was able to see it and access it in nautilus, but when I try to access it in dolphin, I see this:
[image]

Double-clicking on any of the four options does nothing, as if I didn't double-click.  How do I access my files?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know why nobody ever answered to this but if you're using the `SMB` protocol I've got an easy solution to access your local and remote network shares.

1. Right click on the *Remote* header in the *Places* panel on Dolphin
2. Click on "add entry"
3. Give it a name (something like "`SMB Share`")
4. In the "location" input, type in your SMB server location (e.g.: `smb://<ip_address>/folder`)
5. Choose an icon and validate

Now you should see  that icon under your personal folder on the left, just click on it and you will access your network share

Comment: Usually when I use nautilus, the address starts with afp://

Comment: @CurticeGough probably because you're using an Apple device? Did you try using it ? Replace smb:// by afp://

Comment: actually it's a NAS.  I never use Apple products anymore.

Comment: Then it seems like you're using the AppleShare protocol. Can you use another one like SMB ? Idk if I can help you with that. Try with afp://<ip_address> and see if that works

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Right-clicking on the Dolphin sidebar gives me "Add Entry", not "Add Element".  "Add Entry" seems to have a different purpose.

Comment: @PaulA. sorry, I've probably used the wrong term since I'm using Ubuntu in a different language. What do you see in there?

Comment: Adding the mount to Dolphin doesn't also add it to KDialog. That sucks rather badly because it means you can't open files from the network from apps AFAIKT. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am stuck on step 0. Where is the remote header. I am looking in places.

Comment: This worked 100%

Comment: Please note that in order to access a shared folder you also need to setup Samba and in fact first create and share a network folder on your computer. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access it without mounting it, though you might be able to do it by adding an entry to /etc/fstab.If you can get at it, it should be visible under Devices in the left column of the Dolphin screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the location bar (above the file list panel) put a path in this format:

```
smb://username@hostname/path
```

or just

```
smb://hostname
```

You can also use IP addr if the hostname cannot be resolved.
I sometimes also use `.local` MDNS suffix in the hostname part to help to resolve the IP address.