# Accessing SMB share on DNS-323 that requires login

Tags: networking, kde, samba, nas

I have a DNS 323 NAS and set up the SMB Share. I've tested the access on Windows, so it working. It connected, and asked for login and password, and showed the files.

But I cannot access the SMB using my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in which I'm using KDE as the desktop.

- [The Dolphin solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/963670/480954) cannot connect, even I've written

  `smb://user@192.168.1.1/` on the location.
- I've tested with smb_client, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1050460/480954)

  ```
  $ smbclient -L //192.168.1.1
  protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED
  ```
- Also tested the `cifs` [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171059/480954) did not work, either.

  ```
  $sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user //192.168.1.1 /media/NAS/
  mount: /media/NAS: special device //192.168.1.1/ does not exist.
  ```

Is there something that I'm missing so that I can connect to my NAS using my Linux machine?

Comment: I connect successfully to my Synology NAS in 20.04.1 using the following line in my fstab `//192.168.1.117/share_name /media/NAS/share_name cifs username=user_name,password=user_password,rw,uid=1000,gid=500

`

Comment: @User24601 Thanks, that requires the password written, though, I have got this error `mount: /media/NAS: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.`

Comment: the username and password can be saved in a separate file. Sorry, my bad formatting.. there is a space between cifs and username

Comment: did you install cifs-utils? `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`The file I mentioned is .smbcredentials to store user and password

Comment: @User24601 no it is not installed. After installation, now with this in fstab `//192.168.1.1 /media/NAS cifs username=user,password=passwd,rw,uid=1000,gid=500` returns `mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)` with `sudo mount /media/NAS`

Comment: there should not be a line break after cifs but a space before continuing with username=xxxx,password=xxx

Comment: not required in my case but [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032238/307670) answer suggests using vers=1.0

Comment: ``//192.168.0.102/Volume_1 /media/NAS cifs vers=1.0,noauto,users,username=User,password=Pass,iocharset=utf8`` This solved. The final mistake was the required `Volume_1` that Windows did not required. Thanks for the help. If you want, write a answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Synology NAS in 20.04.1 I can successfully access my NAS by adding the following to my fstab file:

```
//192.168.1.117/share_name /media/NAS/share_name cifs username=user_name,password=pass_word,rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

and `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

After some experimentation, the OP has found that the following line in his fstab works seamlessly:

```
//192.168.0.102/Volume_1 /media/NAS cifs vers=1.0,noauto,users,username=User,password=Pass,iocharset=utf8
```

where instead of the share_name he has included /Volume_1 set at the time of initialising the NAS which Windows did not require to establish the connection under that regime.