# Ubuntu Server 20.04 refuses to mount SMB share from Fstab or CMD

Tags: 20.04, cifs, smb

I have tried multiple times with multiple ways to mount my nas to my Ubuntu server LXC for plex usage. For backstory, I am running a LXC container on proxmox with ubuntu server 20.04, with all the packages up to date. As for my nas, I am running unraid that is also fully up to date as well. Whenever I try to mount my nas, I always get this error, no matter if I am trying from the CMD or /etc/fstab file.

```
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

This is the contents of the fstab:

```
//192.168.1.17/Plex  /mnt/Plex cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0
```

I also have tried setting the version tag to 3.11 for smb.

I can see all of my folders and shares with smbclient however...

```
root@Plex:~# smbclient -L //192.168.1.17
Enter WORKGROUP\root's password: 
Anonymous login successful

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        Docker          Disk      Docker Images for Lancache and NextCloud
        NextCloud       Disk      Nextcloud Share
        Plex            Disk      
        Proxmox         Disk      Temp Proxmox
        Storage         Disk      Unraid Server
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Media server)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Any help is apricated. Thank you!

UPDATE: I have updated my stab file to the following:

```
//192.168.1.17/Plex  /mnt/Plex cifs vers=1.0,noauto,users,username=admin,password=1234,rw,iocharset=utf8
```

it now mounts with no errors, but plex does not detect any files in that directory, even after chmod the plex user to that directory. LS brings nothing up either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing SMB share on DNS-323 that requires login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307446/accessing-smb-share-on-dns-323-that-requires-login)

Comment: It allows me to mount the volume now, but now no files are showing up. I am going to fiddle with it some more and then report back.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still unable to access any files whenever I cd into the directory and then try to list anything, but I am now not getting any errors when mounting. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same issue today with the 5.4.0-72 kernel. I solved it by downgrading to the 5.4.0-70 kernel.