# Accessing NAS drive in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, nas

I'm new to Ubuntu and the world of Linux and am trying to get my Intel NUC with Ubuntu to access my NAS drive.
I've done a fair bit of researching and have so far installed samba and added client min protocol = CORE to the conf file.
This got me a little further as it would then see the volume_1 of the NAS and not just the NAS name.

Then I installed cifs but what I found for the lines of code to allow access to the drive lost me.

I get the error of unmounted folder with software access error.

So can anyone do a walk through of how to get Ubuntu to access my NAS please?

Much thanks

Comment: What kind of NAS are you using? This will help someone offer more specific support.

Comment: Western Digital. Kinda old as only 1TB. Do you need the exact model to help?

Answer (score 7):

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and took the following steps to successfully mount my Synology NAS in ~/etc/fstab. These steps were also taken in 18.04 LTS

In the NAS, I set up a share (such as Common_Files) and the users/passwords to access the share in the NAS

Then in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

create the mount point:
`sudo mkdir /media/NAS/Common_Files` (or whatever you wish to call your share)

Identify the ip address of your NAS (in my case I set it to a fixed address in my router).

In fstab create the following line (replace n and nnn with the details of your ip address:

```
//192.168.n.nnn/Common_Files /media/NAS/Common_Files cifs username=your_user_name_in_NAS,password=your_password_in_NAS_share,rw,uid=1000,gid=500
```

To check that it mounts in terminal `sudo mount -a` The share mounts cleanly on reboot.

To provide a desktop link to the share I added Desktop Icons NG (DING) in GNOME Extensions. Using Settings in the Extension (right click on the desktop) and select `Settings` and select `Show external drives in the desktop` GnV_Common is the share name to common files on my NAS.

[image]

I also provided an accepted answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307465/307670) for reference.

UPDATE Dec 2023
These measures continue to work in 22.04 LTS, 23.04 and 23.10 interim releases.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see how that works out. Finding out the IP address should be fun as been years since this was originally set up.

Comment: @MikeSacher to find [ip addresses](https://techwiser.com/find-ip-address-of-any-device/) or just log in to your router 192.168.1.1 in the address bar in your browser.

Comment: These steps worked great!

Comment: Yay, bit of a faff, but got there in the end, thankyou for your efforts in writing this and the other answer, it's appreciated :)